# How to set a "rule" to apply automatically a font to a certain word?

Tags: adobe-indesign, automation, paragraph-styles

I'm translating a document in Adobe InDesign. There is a sort of rule that make the word "Action" italic every time I type it in. Where can I modify that rule? I need to add a similar rule for the translation of "Action".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done using `GREP Styles`, a feature of Paragraph Styles (CS4+). You can assign a Character Style to a specific word or abstractly described string of characters. ('GREP' is originally a UNIX command for programmers to search large source code files for specific code patterns.) Use the online help for details.